# Anyone know how I can go about recreating this logo using shapes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, resource-recommendations

A friend of mine made a logo for me a while ago, and I wanted to take an attempt at recreating it but I'm having a bit of trouble. I'd like to just use hexagons and rectangles to recreate it, but I'm not sure exactly how to do so. does anyone have any idea? All help is appreciated, thanks!

Example

[image]

Comment: First step would be to *not* use Photoshop.

Comment: You should use a vector drawing application for this. Like Illustrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd avoid using Photoshop to be honest. Ultimately, vector software is better for logos.

One possible approach would be to draw everything with the Pen Tool (Bézier Tool) using an isometric grid, and snap to grid, and then fill each shape with the required colour.  This would work using almost any vector software.  In fact it's quite possible that this is how your friend made it in the first place, since the original design is quite close to following an isometric grid anyway.

This example was made in Inkscape, but you could also use Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Corel Draw, etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using the isometric grid, I was able to remake it! https://i.imgur.com/9pvKnAo.png

Answer (score 3):

It can be replicted by using hexagons and rectangles as guides. Have a good quality bitmap image in the bottom as your reference. Lock it to keep it unmovable during the work. Do the job in Illustrator or other vector drawing program to get a freely scalable version.

In the next image the reference is my bad copy of copy of your screenshot It's not even black, but that doesn't prevent using it to show the method. The job is done in Inkscape.

[image]

Draw the red and green hexagons. They very likely should have the same centerpoint. The bad reference image forces to guess their relative sizes.

Draw a few rectangles. The blue one meets 2 corners of the red hexagon. The magenta ones are identical and they both go through 2 corners of the red hexagons. If you have all point snaps on the drawing is very easy.

In Illustrator you could fill the wanted white area with the shape builder, delete the extras and change the green hexagon to black with right width. Inkscape hasn't Shape Builder. There it's easiest to draw the needed shapes with the Bezier Curve tool (="the Pen"). It needs only clicking. Draw at first the black closed polygon and then the orange polygon.

[image]

Send the orange backwards in the stack to make the black visible for the next step. Make a hole by subtracting the black shape from the orange shape (Path > Difference). In Illustrator there's Pathfinder panel for such operations.

Select the actually needed parts, move them apart for recoloring and delete the no more needed junk

[image]